# HTML/CSS adding a video to a slider

Tags: html, css

I am using flexslider on the homepage of my website and currently have images within it, which is fine. But I want to add a video I created which plays automatically and then resumes the action of the slider. I think my problem is in the formatting as I am not at all skilled in HTML or CSS etc. Here is the HTML for the slider:

```
    <div class="flexslider">
      <ul class="slides">
        <li class="slideVideo"></li>
        <li class="slide1"><a href="/portfolioMAIN.html#tabs-2"></a></li>
        <li class="slide2"><a href="/portfolioMAIN.html#tabs-1"></a></li>
        <li class="slide3"><a href="/portfolioMAIN.html#tabs-3"></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

and this is the code in the CSS.

```
    ul.slides li { height:350px; }
    ul.slides li.slide1 a { background:url("/images/doorstop_carousel.png") 0 0 no-repeat; background-size:cover; height:350px; display:block; }
    ul.slides li.slide2 a { background:url("/images/brisant_carousel.png") 0 0 no-repeat; background-size:cover; height:350px; display:block; }
    ul.slides li.slide3 a { background:url("/images/eurosecure_carousel.png") 0 0 no-repeat; background-size:cover; height:350px; display:block; }
    ul.slides li.slideVideo a { background:url("/videos/ident.mp4") 0 0 no-repeat; background-size:cover; height:350px; display:block; }
```

Any help is much appreciated. PS the video is uploaded to my server

Comment: Are you sure that sound (mp4) is `background`? Put _normally_ mp4 object into HTML.

Answer (score 2):

In **HTML5** use `<video>` instead of background `mp4`

```
<li class="slideVideo">
  <video width="480" height="320" controls="controls">
    <source src="/videos/ident.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

User HTML5 `<video>` tag in you list item.

```
 <video width="320" height="240" controls>
   <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
```

Check this link http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

I think you should look at this cool demo.

http://www.menucool.com/slider/play-html5-video-or-audio-in-slider